# Window.Locaton.reload() behaves differently in different browsers (fire fox , Chrome)

Tags: javascript

I am quite new to JavaScript, I have written some code that just reloads the page

`window.location.reload()`

When I run the application in Firefox it re-posts the form and when I run the application in Chrome it redirects to another page.

What are the mechanism of the browsers (Firefox, Chrome) when the page is reloaded using `window.location.reload()`?

Comment: I doubt that reload function does any post request, Can you give a sample /example on how did u tested/concluded same

Comment: @Nadeem - please ensure you are using `window.location.reload()` not the original `Window.Location.reload()` you posted in your question. JavaScript is case sensitive. Also, can you explain what other page Chrome displays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to w3school. The reload() method does the same as the reload button in your browser

syntax is

```
location.reload(forceGet)
```

forceGet is optional. default false which reloads the page from the cache. Set this paramter to true if you want to force the browser to get the page from the server

also you can use href for reload the page.

```
window.location.href="";
```